# Should a custom http header or a parameter by used to identify the context of a caller to a RESTful service?

Tags: rest, http-headers

My team has inherited a WCF service that serves as a gateway into multiple back-end systems. The first step in every call to this service is a decision point based on a context key that identifies the caller. This decision point is essentially a factory to provide a handler based on which back end system the request should be directed to.

We're looking at simplifying this service into a RESTful service and are considering the benefits and consequences of passing the context key as part of the request header rather than adding the context key as a parameter to **every** call into the service. On the one hand, when looking at the individual implementations of the service for each of the backend systems, the context of the caller seems like an orthogonal concern. However, using a custom header leaves me with a slightly uncomfortable feeling since an essential detail for calls to the service are masked from the visible interface. I should note that this is a purely internal solution, which mitigates some of my concern about the visibility of the interface, but even internally there's no telling whether the next engineer to attempt to connect to or modify the service is going to be aware of this hidden detail.